# notifyPropertyChange() within one component to propagate to parent component in EmberJs

Tags: ember.js, components, publish-subscribe

In one component, I am doing `this.notifyPropertyChange('foo')` within an action.

The change to `foo` is indeed picked up within the component, and the updates applied in the template rendering automatically.

However, the parent component passes in `foo` and an attribute to the child component,
and I would like for the parent component to pick up on the change to `foo` initiated within the child component.

How can I do this?

Comment: data binding is fairly bread and butter, can you show me the difference between my parent/child component relationship here and yours, http://emberjs.jsbin.com/vumami/1/edit

Comment: Encountered the same problem, did you solve it?